# Qemu with binfmt in chroot

Tags: chroot, qemu, binfmt

I have downloaded some firmware and I want to run some commands in it. I have extracted the firmware, installed qemu and configured binfmts. The problem is that binfmt does not work in the chroot.

Mipsel files are automatically executed by qemu-mipsel-static:

```
firmware$ bin/ls
/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0: No such file or directory
```

The command qemu-mipsel-static is available within the chroot:

```
firmware$ sudo chroot . /usr/bin/qemu-mipsel-static /bin/ls
webroot     tmp         sbin        media       home        dev
```

When combining the two, it no longer works:

```
firmware$ sudo chroot . /bin/ls
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/ls’: No such file or directory
```

It says "No such file or directory". Is there any way to get more information about this, for example which file can not be found? Is this indeed a problem with binfmt?

My binfmt config looks like this:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu-mipsel 
enabled
interpreter /usr/lib/binfmt-support/run-detectors
flags: 
offset 0
magic 7f454c4601010100000000000000000002000800
mask ffffffffffffff00fffffffffffffffffeffffff
```

Is it a problem that /usr/lib/binfmt-support/run-detectors is not available in the chroot?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it a problem that /usr/lib/binfmt-support/run-detectors is not available in the chroot?

Yes, you need to have the interpreter (and everything it needs) inside the chroot. On my system, `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu-mipsel` contains

```
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/qemu-mipsel-static
flags: OC
offset 0
magic 7f454c4601010100000000000000000002000800
mask ffffffffffffff00fefffffffffffffffeffffff
```

You should try either adding `run-detectors` and everything it needs in your chroot, or reconfiguring `binfmt-misc` to use `qemu-mips-static` directly.

Comment: Thanks. I tried putting the libs for `run-detectors` in the chroot, but this didn't work. Then I removed qemu, binfmt-support and qemu-users-static and reinstalled them. After that the `run-detectors` was no longer in my binfmt config, and it looked like yours. Now it works correctly.